# Escape Key in the Chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

In the chat, we often use backticks highlight code inside of sentences, exactly like `how we do it here`.

Unfortunately, it's located peculiarly close to the `esc` key, which has a nasty effect of clearing the chat input.

Outside of making a userscript, would it be alright to disable that effect so that I (and probably a bunch of others) don't throw my computer out the window when I lose a larger post to a misplaced keystroke?

Note: `command+z` (OSX) does not undo the delete.

Comment: Was about to comment about `control|command+Z` not working. That's the part that bugs me. There is no going back.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3161/chat-easy-input-tools-provides-keyboard-shortcuts-for-common-text-formatting-c relevant.

Comment: yeah I didn't even knew that happened until today.. I cant think of a reason I would need to suddenly clear my entire input.

Comment: @rlemon post that as an answer. It has my upvote and it'll reach more people that way

Comment: @RUJordan done and done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as a workaround for people I have created a userscript that offers keyboard shortcuts for common text formatting in the chats.

you can see the script here: [Chat Easy Input Tools - Provides keyboard shortcuts for common text formatting commands](https://stackapps.com/questions/3161/chat-easy-input-tools-provides-keyboard-shortcuts-for-common-text-formatting-c)

Installing it is a little strange (sorry it is not on the play store) - you need to download the file and open chrome://extensions and drag and drop it to the page.

#### How to use.

*All of the following commands are run if the user has focus in the chat input area.*

- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> inserts a link.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> inserts a [site-tag](/questions/tagged/site-tag).
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> formats text to **bold**.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> formats text to *italics*.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> formats text to <strike>strike-through</strike>.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> formats text to `code`.